# How to fix the DOM in Mobile Safari

Tags: html, iphone, css, dom

I have a one page website with six sections. I would like each section to fill the entire screen or viewport (specifically an iPhone 4s). Currently, it is like each section is stacked on top of each other (this is not what I want).

HTML Tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="intial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

HTML (only posting one section - each section is essentially the same):

```
<section class="container" id="music">
<div class="center">
    <div class="info">
    <h1 class="headline">music</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Black Hour EP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">You're Invited (Coming Soon)</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS @media query:

```
@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       (min-resolution: 192dpi),
       (min-resolution: 2dppx) {

    #home{width: 100%;
        background-image: url(../images/landingPage@2x.jpg);}

    #navbar{display: none;}

    #albumCover{width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        margin-top: 175px;}

    #albumCover p{font-size: 6em;
        padding-top: 150px;}

    #about{width: 100%;
        background-image: url(../images/about@2x.jpg);}

    .info{width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 200px 0 0 200px;}

    .headline{font-size: 3em;
        margin: -20px 0 5px 0;}

    .info p{padding-top: 30px;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-bottom: -100px;}

    #music{width: 100%;
        background-image: url(../images/music@2x.jpg);}}

    .info ul li{text-align: center;
        font-family: eb-garamond, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 2em;
        text-transform: capitalize;}

        /* Lighthouse */
        iframe{width: 50%;
            height: 50%;}

        #close{margin: 50px 0 15px 350px;
            padding: auto 5px;}

    #videos{width: 100%;
        background-image: url(../images/videos@2x.jpg);}}

    #connect{width: 100%;
        background-image: url(../images/connect@2x.jpg);}}

    #contact{width: 100%;
        background-image: url(../images/contact@2x.jpg);}}

    #email a{font-size: .625em;}

    .primeLine{font-size: 1em;}

    #email li{margin: 0;}   

}
```

Here is a screen shot of the current state: http://postimg.org/image/ya1488ebb/

Does anybody have any ideas that could help me out or get me thinking along the right track?

Comment: You want to have the 6 blocks, expand their width to the browser's window size and scroll down to access the rest of the blocks?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to have happen. Each block has a different background-image.

Comment: You can find the answer below. If you are satisfied, please mark the question as answered!

Answer (score 2):

Then, I think this will solve your problem, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enbs/NZUWj/).

You can add individual backgrounds to the different DIV's, margin, text, absolute elements, etc.

```
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Boris, this gets me closer. However, no each <section> looks like it is stacked on top of each other - like sheets of paper.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean? You can add **margin: 5px 0;** to the top and bottom of each div. Could you please provide us with, perhaps, an image of what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: here is the link for the desktop: www.iamparisjones.com/newsite

Comment: The desktop site is powered by JavaScript. That't how you are able to scroll to specific content on click. That make's this a totally different question, partly but not completely css related. It could be done with CSS entirely using **[:target](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp)**. If you play around with it for a while, you can get it to be as smooth. Anyhow the scrolling on-click feature is not very practical for mobile. I would rather have this as a continuous loop to scroll through.

Comment: @justLearning, there's a plugin called curtain.js that does something similar - you can find an example here: [link](http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/menu-nav/curtain/index.html) The plugin isn't maintained anymore, but the curtain effect has been obscenely popular for a while now so there are plenty of JavaScript options.

Comment: Boris, the desktop version is all done in css. If you have an iPhone visit the same site to see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a z-index to the divs along with box-shadow might provide what you're looking for in terms of the "stacked pages" effect - see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NZUWj/5/

```
.one {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 5px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 5px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

In terms of images, background-image-size and other background-image properties seem pretty widely supported according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts, but if you're concerned about compatibility (IE 8) a javascript solution like backstretch.js might be better.

**That being said, if your divs don't need to flow and always stay at 100% width, you don't need all those extra CSS properties.** This format will work:

```
.one {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px -5px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px -5px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

See it in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GEdLV/4/

Comment: Marcatectura, sorry for the confusion. I do not want a stacked page look. Technically, I would like them to parallax over each other; however, for now I will take each section placed on top of each other in one column.